# How to set a VNC password?

Tags: password, vnc

Can anyone say me how to set a VNC password in Ubuntu? Such that if anyone access my machine through VNC it should prompt for a password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a password when you open Remote Desktop.

[image]

Or with`vncpasswd` you can also set the password for the vnc-server.

So if someone want to connect to you, he has to enter the password.

Comment: `vncpasswd` doesn't work for me.

Comment: Which vnc server do you use?
Start Options:


vnc4server: Command to start: `vncserver`.
Then run `vncpasswd`.

tightvncserver: Command to start: `tightvncserver`.
Then run `vncpasswd`.

Gnome build in vino-server: Command to start: `vino-preferences`
And Activate: "Allow other users to view your desktop" and set a password.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I forgot the password to the VNC server.  For my situation, the final target was TightVNC running on Ubuntu 18.04 which I needed to reach from my mac.

You first kill the existing VNC sessions with

```
vncserver -kill :1
```

Use something like this to find out if you've killed all sessions.  Usually, the vncserver is running on port 5901:

```
sudo netstat -peanut | grep "vncserver"
```

If there is something, repeat the kill command with the appropriate `vncserver -kill :2` or whatever listing.  If nothing, then you can remove the default original password setting with:

```
sudo rm ~/.vnc/passwd
```

Restart the vncserver as:

```
vncserver
```

And you'll be prompted again for a new password.  The daemon should run on port 5901, which you can query with the `netstat` command above.