# How to run KOHA-Ubuntu server without keyboard/mouse/monitor?

Tags: 16.04, remote

I've a KOHA-Ubuntu server (Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) running in my office LAN and accessible by http. Now, due to space crunch in the room I want to run the CPU only without keyboard/mouse/monitor and want to control it by remote login (rdesktop application or like that). Is it really possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple remote desktop solutions, and multiple programs for each method. The way I set this up is with VNC and the `tightvncserver` package.

1. Run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt install tightvncserver`
2. Start the server from the command line with `tightvncserver`

Now you can access the VNC server from a VNC viewer. The Remmina Remote Desktop Client that comes with Ubuntu will work just fine, and RealVNC should work just fine on Windows and Mac.

To connect, simply use your server's local IP and screen in the VNC Viewer like this: 192.168.1.x:1 (to find your server's local IP, run `ifconfig`)

To start the VNC server automatically on boot, see this question: [How do I start VNC Server on boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/120973/how-do-i-start-vnc-server-on-boot)

To set or change the VNC password, see this question: [How to set a VNC password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36715/how-to-set-a-vnc-password)

I choose TightVNC because it is light on resources, and creates a separate desktop, rather than share the monitor window. Because of this, you can stop the `lightdm` service with `sudo service lightdm stop` to kill the monitor window and save system resources. (If you need to connect a monitor to the system, you can login at the command line [Ctrl+Alt+F1] and run `sudo service lightdm start`)